# MySQL usando variáveis no select

Tags: mysql, sql

Já busquei em alguns tutoriais mas não acho um expecífico de como declarar a variável no select pelo MySQL, segue o que estou tentando fazer.

```
DECLARE @idPedido INT;
DECLARE @idCombo INT;

SELECT @idPedido = idPedido, @idCombo = idCombo 
FROM Pedidos
WHERE idCombo IS NOT NULL;

SELECT @idPedido;
SELECT @idCombo;
```

Comment: Você esta fazendo o select e quer mudar o nome da variável que é retornada, isto ?

Comment: eu quero criar as variáveis e adicionar o valor desses campos dentro delas.

Comment: Isto é mais complicado de se fazer, se fosse somente trocar o nome poderia usar `SELECT idPedido as novaVariavel `...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso queria uma variável pré-definida, use o `SET`:

```
-- seta o valor da variável
SET @idPedido = 10;

-- imprime o valor
SELECT @idPedido;  --neste caso, o retorno será 10
```

---

Utilizando uma *query* para pesquisar e setar as variáveis:

```
-- setando a variável (utiliza-se :=)
SELECT @idPedido := idPedido, @idCombo := idCombo 
FROM Pedidos
WHERE idCombo IS NOT NULL;

-- imprime o valor
SELECT @idPedido, @idCombo;
```

> ATENÇÃO: neste exemplo acima, se o "`SELECT`" retorna vários
>   resultados, e com isso as variáveis serão setadas conforme o último valor
>   retornado pela consulta, pois ela é substituída conforme o corre o processo de consulta e atualização.

Answer (score 2):

Voce está misturando tudo.

Para fazer select faça assim:

```
 SELECT idPedido, idCombo 
 FROM Pedidos
 WHERE idPedido = @idPedido AND idCombo = @idCombo
```

e para fazer update faça assim:

```
 UPDATE Pedidos set idPedido = @idPedido, idCombo = @idCombo 
 WHERE id = 1
```

Para fazer o select atribuindo os valores retornados à variaveis faça assim:

```
DECLARE @idPedido INT;
DECLARE @idCombo INT;

SELECT idPedido, idCombo into @idPedido, @idCombo
FROM Pedidos
WHERE idCombo = 1;
```

Atenção o SELECT tem de retornar 1 e apenas uma linha.

Comment: era isso não, ele não ta atribuindo o valor na variável.

Comment: obrigada, era isso.